# MySQL generate sql insert for depended tables

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, dependencies, generator

I need create sql script for insert in many tables - total near 2000, but tables linked (it is an xml adjancency model) - so after have inserted in table1, receive id, add some data, insert into fk of table2 - previous id, and data, after repeat for table3, for table 4,...
Length of chain of linked tables - more than 20.
The question is: exists some code generator that can read relations between tables from information schema and - after point some table as root - generate all tree of insert query?
Thanks.

Comment: are the tables linked with one key? such as "id" or are there multiple different keys from each table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't do it on application layer, I suggest trying to do it with [Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html).

Essentially, you would create an "AFTER INSERT" Trigger on each of the tables. Smth like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1
AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table2 (id, attrib2) VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.attrib2);
END

CREATE TRIGGER t2
AFTER INSERT ON table2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table3 (id, attrib3) VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.attrib3);
END
```

Then, an insert into table1 would trigger an insert into table2, which would trigger an insert into table3 and so on.